# vagrant ssh do not finish to start on Windows

Tags: laravel, ssh, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-windows

I'm trying to configure Homestead for Laravel local development on Windows 10. I follow the laravel's documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead

I installed VirtualBox 5.1 and Vagrant 2.0, and of course I cloned the Homestead git repository.

I run **vagrant up** and all is right, but when I run **vagrant ssh**, shows the following message:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-92-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

But doesn't finish to login on console.

Anyone has an idea how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an old issue back in 1.9.6 but seems it is there in latest release again, see https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9143#issuecomment-342536505 if it can help for you

The workaround would be to use putty or running `vagrant ssh` from powershell or command line